# i have problem about google play console app content?

Tags: google-play-console

Please help me. when i try to upload my application on google play console then i select app content but when i go in app content i have option ads and when i click start i have just two disable options save and discard changes.. i have no option to select age please help me .. i created my privacy policy online and put in to google drive link there.. you can see in picture my problem[My Problem here in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfV3j.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to close your adblock and refresh the page